# GDM freezes when logging out in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gdm, logout, display-manager

I have recently done a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04. I have noticed that if I choose the 'Log Out' option, after logging out of the session, the GDM screen does appear, but there is no cursor, and I cannot do anything.

The system doesn't respond to any action, including trying to switch to a free TTY, a hard reboot is the only thing I can do.

It might help with the debugging to note that I also had this issue a couple of days ago (I did multiple (re)installations for various reasons in a short time frame). Prior to that install, I had a Windows 10 partition on my laptop, and I used that install to wipe it out. However on my sdb, which I use as /home, I had the remnants of the D:\ partition of W10. I have deleted that partition and extended the sdb1 /home partition to encompass that space though. After this, the issue **was gone** . This might be coincidental, however.

I can, of course, provide logs, if a potential answerer tells me which logs are needed.

EDIT: In case it matters, I use the ubuntu-gnome-desktop session with Dash-to-Dock, Ubuntu Appindicators and Unite as extensions.

EDIT2: Disabled extensions - doesn't help. Went back to the default Ubuntu session - doesn't help. Installed Gparted and resized /home slightly (see my remark about my past W10 partition) - doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the login display manager from gdm3 to lightdm. LightDM is a more lightweight login display manager than gdm3.

```
sudo apt install lightdm   
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm 
sudo reboot
```

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` will open up a new window allowing you to select lightdm as the default login display manager. Use the arrow keys to select lightdm, press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to put the focus on **<OK>** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then reboot by running this command: `sudo reboot`